# dell powerconnect switch logs

Tags: logging, networking, dell-powerconnect

Is it possible to view an event log on managed Dell PowerConnect switches (using the CLI)?

We use a mix of 6224F, 6224, 3524P, and 3548P switches and having just had some network related issues which affected our entire network and I'm curious to know where I should start looking to identify the cause.

Actually I'm pretty sure I've identified the culprit in this instance, but I'd prefer not to have to go round the building physically inspecting all data points in future, so any tips or pointers would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really hate answering my own question, but I've found the info I was seeking.

**Via the console**

`show logging` displays the in memory log file

**Transfer via TFTP**

`copy operational-log tftp://a.b.c.d/log.file` - copies the log to a TFTP server, however I haven't had much luck with this yet. I get an empty file.

**Write to syslog server**

`logging {ip-address | hostname}` I'm thinking this is probably the way forward for me.

Comment: Of course you need Privileged EXEC Mode for this  (enter by typing **enable** in the stanard CLI)

Answer (score 0):

There's no event log per se, but there are a plethora of counters, statistics, summaries, charts, etc. that can be viewed on a managed PowerConnect switch. Connect to the web management interface of the switch and look for a node labeled "Statistics".

Comment: Thanks Joe. I did manage to find logging on the switches in the end (see my answer), the level of logging appears to be different between the 6xxx and 3xxx range. The 6xxx range does seem to offer far better functionality.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out.